# Why command+v print out numbers why?

Tags: monterey, keybindings

I was googling about the sign for square root on the keyboard and found `command+v` but when I press it, it gives math eq like `2*2+2*2+2`. It is like it is built into it. why does the `command+v` gives you such math eq? and as a developer what can I use to denote square root?

Answer (score 3):

You mean this… **√** ?

That's on  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>

There are **no** characters/glyphs accessed by the  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  key at all.  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>  is Paste.
You can find more complex glyphs using the Character Viewer [Emoji & Symbols]. Double-click the glyph in the viewer to enter it at the caret.

Image showing both on-screen keyboard [slightly different design on newer macOS, this is from Mojave] with the Character Viewer below, searching 'root'.

[image]